# Rsync file permissions

Tags: rsync, file-permissions

I am building a script to copy files from a remote server. The problem is, the remote servers file permissions are pretty whack and I don't want to copy these over.

The line in my script right now is

`/usr/bin/rsync -rtzul --progress -e ssh "$DEFAULT_SSH:$REMOTE_DIRECTORY" "$LOCAL_DIRECTORY"`

I have seen elsewhere that you can use the `--chmod` option to specify the permissions but I just don't understand the syntax for this argument! Perhaps I am being stupid?

I want to by default chmod files to `644` and directories to `755`. I hope you can help me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have worked out how to do it! I had been digging for some time before asking this question and continued digging. The arguments I were looking for are -

`--chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r`

**To explain, this basically means:**

Du = Directory Owner (`Read, write, execute`)

Dg = Directory Group (`Read, execute`)

Do = Directory Users (all) (`Read, execute`)

Fu = File Owner (`Read, write`)

Fg = File Group (`Read`)

Fo = File Users (all) (`Read`)

So in my case I have given directories `755` permissions and files `644` permissions.

I found out how to do this from - http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: I think you can write something shorter
--chmod=Du=rwx,g=rx,o=rx,Fu=rw,g=r,o=r